# GUI front-end for ISC's DHCP Server on Debian

Tags: windows, gratis

I am creating pools at work with the `isc-dhcp-server` package, and editing a very large `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` file. I don't want there to be any hiccups, so I'd like to visualize it on my Windows PC.

- Must connect to `isc-dhcp-server`, hosted on a Debian console, within the same LAN subnet
- Free (as in beer)
- Must support all the `dhcpd.conf` switches (especially pools)
- Syntax-checker for all the commands
- Bonus: runs over SSH (for encryption)

Answer (score 1):

I found out that **Webmin** supports it, right out of the box.

> - Must connect to isc-dhcp-server, hosted on a Debian console, within the same LAN subnet (*It does, through a browser)
> - Free (as in beer) (*Installed through apt-get with the default repositories*)
> - Must support all the dhcpd.conf switches (especially pools) (*It actually regenerates the DHCP Configuration files as you're changing settings - Including formatting them nicely*)
> - Syntax-checker for all the commands (*It generates the dhcpd.conf file as you're changing settings with the GUI*)
> - Bonus: runs over SSH (for encryption) (*Runs over HTTPS by default*)

After doing an `apt-get update && apt-get install webmin` from the root login on the server, I could navigate to `https://servername:10000`. I did have to do another [hack to get Internet Explorer 11 to let me in](http://blog.oracle48.nl/internet-explorer-10-continue-to-this-website-option-missing/) (self signed certificates), by executing `certutil -setreg chain\minRSAPubKeyBitLength 512` while running the Command Prompt as the Administrator.

Once I got in, I could go in and change all the little settings I needed.